# Weird Error when defining new migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Every time I execute add-migration command on package manage console to update my database schema, I get this error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Apply' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalColumnAttributeConvention' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation. at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalConventionSetBuilder.AddConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.AddConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef1.get_Value() at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String name, String outputDir, String context, String environment, Action1 reporter)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
Method 'Apply' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalColumnAttributeConvention' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not ha ve an implementation.
```

anyone encountered this issue before ?!

Comment: You should consider a better title for your question that describes the error. "Weird Error" is not helpful to later users nor is it search friendly.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you updated your packages to the latest version? I remember seeing this on mismatched versions. See this issue for similar issue and solution: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7056

Comment: it's a problem produced by visual studio because after the restoration of dotnet with cache's cleaning, everything goes well.
I just execute this command via console : dotnet restore --no-cache
Thank you any way =)